# Declaration found during unqualified name lookup

Tags: c++, global-scope

Consider the following simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int a=5;//1
extern int a;//2

int main(){ cout << a; }
```

The standard said that (sec. 3.4/1):

> Name lookup shall find an unambiguous declaration for the name

and (sec. 3.4.1/1):

> name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name.

**Question:** What declaration (1 or 2) will be found in my case and why?

Comment: #2 is a declaration, #1 is definition.

Comment: @RakibulHasan every definition is declaration (see 3.1)).

Comment: yes. I just tried to focus on that on definition . more accurate would be #1 is declaration+definition.

Comment: @RakibulHasan I don't think so that it is make a sense to name #1 as declaration+definition because set of all definitions is a subset of all declarations. But my questions is not about it. I want to clarify what exactly declaration will be found in my case? I read clause 3.4.1 about unqualified name lookup, but don't understand that yet. Can you clarify this moment?

Comment: if compiler does not reorder statements, it should find `int a` first, and according to the first statement, it should stop immediately.

Answer (score 2):

That clause says that name lookup stops when it hits `int a=5;`

There is only one name here, `a` in the global namespace. It's not ambiguous because there is only one `a`, it doesn't matter if there are multiple declarations of `a`. Two declarations, one name. (The "ambiguous" case can only occur for class member name lookup, which is more fully described in that section).

I get the sense from your wording that you are expecting there to be some sort of different behaviour depending on whether 1 or 2 satisfies this clause; but there isn't.