# Is usual unqualified lookup for the function name differs from lookup for variable name?

Tags: c++, function, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int a=5;//1
extern int a;//2

int main(){ cout << a; }
```

During unqualified name lookup declaration#1 will be found and unqualified name lookup ends just after #1 is found.

But consider another example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() { cout << "zero arg"; }
void foo(int a) { cout << "one arg"; }

int main(){ foo(4); }
```

In that case `void foo();`'s definition will be found first. But unqualified name lookup doesn't end. Why? **Where is it specified in the standard**? In general, I'm interested in:

**When does unqualified name lookup ends for the postfix-expression for the function call?**

*Note:* I know what does ADL mean. The set of declarations produced by ADL is empty in that  case.

UPD:

But if we write the following:

```
int foo(int a) { return 0; }
namespace A
{
    int foo() { return 1; }
    int a= foo(5); //Error: to many arguments
}
```

This implies that enclosing namespace does not considering. I would like to know where is it specified too.

Comment: `extern int a` is just a redeclaration of the previous `a`. You cannot really tell which `a` is used because there is only one `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In that case void foo();'s definition will be found first. But unqualified name lookup doesn't end. Why?

Because standard says:

> Name lookup may associate more than one declaration with a name if it finds the name to be a function name; the declarations are said to form a set of overloaded functions (13.1). Overload resolution (13.3) takes place after name lookup has succeeded.

So in case of function, *name lookup* does not end after finding first match, it collects all the *names*, and then *overload resolution* occurs.

**Update**

For the updated question, you are back to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966473/declaration-found-during-unqualified-name-lookup)

> name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name.

So as soon as `foo` is found in *inner scope*, no further search is conducted.

But if you use *namespace qualified* name, then the specified namespace will be searched:

```
int a = ::foo(5); // finds foo in global namespace.
```

So in general, for *unqualified search*, first search is conducted in the current scope, if not found then next enclosing scope and so forth. However, as soon as a name is found, search ends, it does not matter if **the name is usable or not**. It means, for function, it may not be the correct one, may be there is an overloaded one in enclosing scope which is correct, but search does not continue to that.

Comment: But unqualified name lookup doesn't collect the function's name appeared into enclosing declarative region. Is it specified somewhere in the standard?